# How can you retreive images from firebase and display in gridview android

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, gridview

I created a listview and recycler/card view with firebase no problem, but I cannot do a gridview involving pictures using picasso library. I have been trying for 3 days now.

Can someone point me in the correct direction? I can't seem to find any tutorials or videos on such process...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `GridLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView` instead of a GridView. Since your code is working for `RecyclerView`. It's more efficient to use `RecyclerView` anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i did.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this process will work for you.

Define GridView in your layout like this

```
 <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"></GridView>
```

Create an adapter inflating layout like this,

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Fetch ImageUrl from firebase add in arraylist and provide that arraylist to adapter.

get that imageUrl from arrylist and set to the imageview in adpter by using picasso.

Comment: Thanks, i just implemented a GridLayoutManger with my recycler view :)